# mvc - current URL? not request URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to submit data etc, but when I look at Request.Url etc I get the URL of the Ajax request. Is there a way I can get URL of the actual page the user is on?

Basically, I need to obtain id (routevalue) from the URL without passing anything to the Ajax-actionlink.

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly pass the information you need in the request:

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink(
   "Some link text", 
   "ActionName", 
   // Notice how the id value is extracted from the route
   // and used to construct the link
   new { id = RouteData.Values["id"] },
   new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success" }
) %>
```

Comment: because RouteData.Values get messed up if there's an Ajax request that is updating the div that contains the ActionLink that you just posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `UrlReferrer` property of the `HttpRequest` class. I'm not sure if it will work on every case of your application, but you could give it a try.

Comment: it won't work. If there hasnt been any Ajax calls, URLreferrer will point to incorrect stuff